# Google cloud bucket use for static services without having a domain

Tags: google-cloud-platform, static, google-cloud-storage, load-balancing, bucket

I have a static website that I want to use google bucket for it. However, as I **do not have a domain** I want to directly use the bucket with allUsers permission to view.

In order the users do not see the default folder structures of the bucket I made a load balancer that at least if someone goes to my bucket I directly redirect them to the build/index.html however I get permission error when the bucket is public ( with all of its contents)

I made this setting via IP of the machine that bucket is created on.

[image]

But I get the typical 403 error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to setup advanced host and path rule. The default simple host and path rule option will do.

I found a [similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124162/how-to-disable-google-cloud-storage-bucket-list-from-acl-control) regarding your question. You can prevent users from listing your entire bucket directory by changing the permission from `Storage Object Viewer` to `Storage Legacy Object Viewer`. Since the `Storage Object Viewer` role contains the permissions for both `storage.objects.get` and`storage.objects.list`, this will include permissions to list the objects in the bucket. For a reference list of the IAM roles that apply to cloud storage, see [IAM Roles for Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam#overview).

Next, you can do a "redirect" by assigning build/index.html as a [specialty page](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website#specialty-pages). As for the steps, you can follow:

1. Upload an empty `index.html` file in the root of your bucket.
2. Open the bucket settings and click the `Edit Website Configuration`
3. Set the newly uploaded index.html as the "Main Page"

You can check the [answer of Hao Xu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56354633/16531380), and the [answer of maxime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52502000/16531380) respectively.

Comment: Thanks but number 2 and 3 does not work. Still if I go to my bucket it shows access denied until I add /index.html at the end of the url

Comment: Hi @user3201492, I see your comment but you've already accepted the answer, just wanted to ask if you're okay with it? Can you please clarify?

Comment: Hello! still I have problem that I need to set full URL with index.html but anyhow the point related to  Storage Legacy Object Viewer was very important so that is why I accepted it as an answer ( 80% of the solution )

Comment: @user3201492, can you clarify if there's a conflict in your load balancer? Also, did you edit your host and path rule prior to the second part of my answer?

Comment: I do not have any load balancer indeed. Regarding to the host I actually want to use Cloud Storage to host my static website that is built by React. So I am not sure what do you mean by edit your host then :)

Comment: My impression is that in order the redirect , 404 works the bucket should have a domain name